# is it possible to do sql injection in nodejs with postgres databse when I use "text" and "values"?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, web, graphql

package.json file

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-graphql": "^0.12.0",
    "graphql": "^15.5.0",
    "pg": "^8.5.1"
  }
}
```

My code is

```
database = function(data){
  // I can pass a string or an object type into "data"
  var writeValue = {text:"INSERT INTO mydatabse(value) VALUES($1);",
  values: [data]}
  client.query(writeValue, (err, res) => {
    if (err){
      console.error(err)
      console.log("i got an error!!!")
      return err
    }
  });
  return "hi " + data;
}
```

I can pass a string or an object into `data`

is thar a way to abuse the sql or this is always a safe way to prevent sql injection?

Answer (score 1):

Barring bugs in `pg` library, this should be safe from SQL injections.  Of course it can still insert things you might not want, like text which when pulled back out of the database and naively thrown into a web page might cause the web browser to do bad things.  But that wouldn't be a classic SQL injection, but something else.